# Rails 3 + Rspec 2.0.1 Autotest failing: Ruby on Rails Tutorial by M. Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am running Rails 3.0.1 and Rspec 2.0.1.  I am following M. Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial and having an issue with failing tests on Lesson 5:  Filling in the layout.

When I am running autotest, and constantly getting this error and can't seem to figoure out why:

```
Failures:
  1) UsersController GET 'new' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Sign Up")
     expected following output to contain a <title>Sign Up</title> tag:
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
     <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Sign up</title>
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js""></script>
     <![endif]--><link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/screen.css?1313951692" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/print.css?1313951692" media="media" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <!--[if lt IE 8]><link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/ie.css?1313951692" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><[endif]--><link href="/stylesheets/custom.css?1319319986" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     </head>
     <body>
        <div class="container">

        <nav class="round"><ul>
     <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
            </ul></nav></header><section class="round"><h1>Users#new</h1>
     <p>Find me in app/views/users/new.html.erb</p>

            </section><footer><nav class="round"><ul>
     <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://railstutorial.org">Rails Tutorial</a></li>
            </ul></nav></footer>
     </div>
       </body>
     </html>
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that in your test you have

```
response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Sign Up")
```

But your HTML code is

```
 <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Sign up</title>
```

Your Test and HTML source don't match. Uppercase "up" in the source and you will be good to go.

Comment: @TomKim Yeah, we all do it. It wasn't that long ago (less than a week ago) that I did the exact same thing working through the tutorial. Also, I see you are new here. There is a gray checkmark next to my answer, if I provided the right solution you should check it to show that this question has an acceptable answer. If you ask questions in the future you're more likely to get a better response if you have a high accepted answer percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Its a case problem I think.  Content doesn't have to match exactly but the case does.

Yeah...what Noah said.